# Time format not working in dc.js LineChart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have the following parsing code of time in h:m:s format

```
            var ISO8601format=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
            var hoursandminsformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"); 
            e.time=hoursandminsformat(ISO8601format.parse(e.time));
```

I have a json file with reading at different times from different sensors.
Sample data is=

```
[
{"id":1,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z"},
{"id":2,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z"},
{"id":3,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z"},
{"id":1,"time":"2015-03-29T20:33:24Z"},
{"id":2,"time":"2015-03-29T20:33:24Z"},
{"id":3,"time":"2015-03-29T20:33:24Z"},
]
```

I am going to plot a dc.js rowchart where there will be time in minutes in the x axis and frequency in the y axis. I am using the following code to do this. But its returning NaNs.

```
var freqchart= dc.lineChart("#chart1");
var countByTime=ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.time; });
var freqbyTimeGroup = countByTime.group().reduceCount();
freqchart.width(400).height(200).transitionDuration(500)
    .dimension(countByTime).group(freqbyTimeGroup).elasticY(true).x(
                d3.time.scale().domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.time;}),
                                        d3.max(data,function(d){return d.time;})])).xUnits(d3.time.minutes).yAxisLabel("Frequency").xAxisLabel('Time').elasticX(true)
```

How can I solve this problem? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e67uzfn/21/) that's not working

Comment: Why are you formatting the dates as strings before passing them to crossfilter? `d3.time.scale` is not going to work with strings. I would suggest doing the parse but not the format before crossfilter, and leave the formatting for the ticks. But there must be some reason, as you had this working correctly in another question.

Comment: I am parsing to time formtat using this code var ISO8601format=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
            var hoursandminsformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"); 
            e.time=hoursandminsformat(ISO8601format.parse(e.time));

Comment: Yes, I tested your code and it is formatting the time properly. What I question is why you would format the date as a string before passing it to crossfilter. Ordinarily you will use Date objects in crossfilter and d3, and then only format them to strings for the ticks and labels and such.

Comment: Actually the data I am getting is giving me timestamp in the format given.. I want to show only H:M in the x axis. But its returning NaNs

Comment: The data is coming from hbase and the time format coming is "2015-03-29T20:33:24Z"

Comment: You gave the jsfiddle that worked for separate time. But not working in this case rather its returning NaNs

Comment: I don't think I am making myself clear, but I'm not sure how I can explain this differently. Your first code block, which I guess is running before you pass the data to crossfilter: that code is turning the dates into **strings**. Then you use a bunch of functions for the chart which expect **Dates**. I'm pretty sure this is where your NaNs are coming from, but please post another fiddle if this doesn't help.

Comment: Here is the updated jsfiddle. Can you please have a look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/6e67uzfn/18/

Comment: You can see this fiddle that times are coming correctly http://jsfiddle.net/6e67uzfn/20/

Comment: What is the mistake I am making. I am confused why should this happen. Its exactly your code and data in H:M:S format is right also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray I got the solution. Here is the code

```
   var data=[
    {"id":20,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z","speed":20},
    {"id":21,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z","speed":15},
    {"id":22,"time":"2015-03-29T20:32:24Z","speed":16},
    {"id":23,"time":"2015-03-29T20:33:25Z","speed":14},
    {"id":20,"time":"2015-03-29T20:33:26Z","speed":20},
    {"id":21,"time":"2015-03-29T20:34:24Z","speed":10},
    {"id":22,"time":"2015-03-29T20:34:24Z","speed":15},
    {"id":23,"time":"2015-03-29T20:35:24Z","speed":15},
]
    // The datset is much larger with many detector. This is sample
        var dateformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;
        var ISO8601format=d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
        var hoursandminsformat=d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"); 
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.time=d.time.substring(11,19);
        d.time=dateformat(d.time);
    });
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e67uzfn/23/)